# Does the size of a state variable in a smart contract's storage impact the cost of a transaction?

Tags: solidity, gas, evm

Does the size of a state variable in a smart contract's storage impact the cost of a transaction, even if the variable is not accessed by the executed method? And if it does, to what extend?

For example, in this contract, there's a variable `numbers`.

```
contract Example {

   uint[] public numbers;

   function randomOperation() public view returns(uint) {
      return 2 + 2;
   }

}
```

Let's assume that variable contains a very large number of entries, will the cost of `randomOperation()` be affected by that? Also, if I do modify `numbers` (adding an entry), will the number of entries affect the transaction cost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `reads` and `writes` are deterministic and of constant complexity for the same `Data Element Type` and `Data Element Size`, the current size (*amount of elements*) of an `array` or a `mapping` has **no impact**.

Comment: If said array has a dynamic size, and a huge amount of entries, would that impact the cost of a `write` or `read`?

Comment: Exactly,  no matter how many entries are in the array or mapping, the reads and writes by index or by key will cost the same

Answer (score 0):

`State variables` are stored directly on the blockchain so they can impact the transaction cost if modification of that state variable is being done in that transaction.

As in your scenario, the transaction doesn't involve modification in the `state variable` of the contract, therefor the transaction fees won't be affected.